# In R: Convert from WGS84 lat/long to UTM and back again to WGS84 lat/long

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I am looking for a way in R to project WGS84 latitudes and longitudes to a UTM grid and then convert the UTM coordinates back to the WGS84 latitudes and longitudes. I have found a number of ways to project to a UTM grid (`mapproj::mapproject`, `rgdal::spTransform`), but going from the grid back to latitudes and longitudes seems to be more complicated. Is there a projection function that offers the inverse?

I would like to use find the reverse of this:

```r
newdata <-mapproject(dataset$lon, dataset$lat, projection = "lambert", parameters = c(mean(dataset$lon), mean(dataset$lat)))
```

Comment: What have you researched so far?  There are plenty of places with the generic algorithm for this as well as code snippets of the transformation in various languages.

Comment: Can you please point me to a place that shows how to do this in R?  I am obviously not looking the right way as I haven't found the answer.

Comment: When I get back to the office I can go through my bookmarks, I am pretty sure I have something in there.

Comment: are you looking for something like that  spTransform(x, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can move from any CRS to another CRS, below R code will work. Make sure you know the EPSG code for CRS which you are using. This is a reproducible example for converting from BNG to WGS. Vice versa is also possible.

```
library(raster)
t<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(531366.2,531325.7,259349.5,249798),nrow=2)) #sample coordinates
colnames(t) = c("x", "y")
t_wgs<-spTransform(SpatialPointsDataFrame(t[,c(1,2)],data = t,proj4string = crs("+init=epsg:27700")) , crs("+init=epsg:4326"))
t_wgs$lon<-t_wgs@coords[,1]
t_wgs$lat<-t_wgs@coords[,2]
View(t_wgs@data)
```

EPSG code for BNG is 27000 and WGS84 is 4326